Integral of quotient of two series
Suppose we have two series $f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\ t^n$ and $g(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n\ t^n$ with infinite radius of convergence.  We also suppose that $g(t)$ can have complex zeros but no real zeros.
Now, we want to compute the following integral:
\begin{align*}
I(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} dt
\end{align*}
Knowing the series development for $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, one can formally get the development of $f(t)/g(t)$ and integrate term by term in order to get a development for $I(x)$. Then I have the following questions:
Question 1: Although $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ have an infinite radius of convergence, this may be not the case for $f(t)/g(t)$. Is is true that the radius of convergence of $f(t)/g(t)$ is equal to the distance of the nearest zero of $g(t)$ from the origin ?
In such a case, it would mean that computing $I(x)$ this way is not possible for values beyond this radius of convergence. So,
Question 2: What are the other options (other than series development of $f(t)/g(t)$) for getting an expression for $I(x)$ for all $x$ from the series development of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ ? I suspect that the zeros of $g(t)$ may have some role to play here but I can not see how to use this fact.
I also know that it is possible for rational functions to compute the integral from partial decomposition, so an option would be to truncate the series of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ up to N terms and get successive approximations for $I(x)$.

Q1 is “almost” correct. The radius of convergence of $f/g$ is the distance to the next singularity, and singularities of $f/g$ are at the zeros of $g$ that do not cancel with zeros of $f$.

You might be wanting too much here. If $g(t) = b_0 - t$ with $b_0>0$ and $f(b_0)\ne0$, for instance, then $I(x)$ is legitimately undefined for $x\ge b_0$.

@Greg Martin, ok but I supposed that $g(t)$ has no real zero.

Right, sorry I missed that. Are the $a_n$ and $b_n$ real? If so the complex zeros come in conjugate pairs. Suppose for example that $g(\pm i)=0$. One could try writing $1/g(t)$ as $1/\tilde g(t) + c/(t^2+1)$ for an appropriate constant $c$ and maybe integrating the two parts separately against $f(t)$?
